# jnlp can no longer pass large properties since java 7 upgrade 45

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE !!! 
 The one marked duplicate explains why properties cannot be passed in jre7u45. But my problem is that all but 2 of large properties cannot be passed.

My jnlp have around 30 properties. Out of the 30, 2 properties contain base64 encoded value of a file (Around 1000 chars). Since java 7 upgrade 45, these 2 big properties are not passed when the application is launched.I get all other 28 properties. All these properties starts with "jnlp." so they are secure properties. It was working fine till upgrade 40. 
Is anyone else facing this problem? Any idea why its happening. Are there any known workarounds?
Update:
This [link](http://forums.oracle.com/message/5500341#5500341) mentions similar problem in java 1.6 itself, and the related bug [6728843](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6728843) is still open, but there is nothing in the update 45 revision history which tells me that something has changed in u45 which can impact this behavior.

Comment: *"Are there any known workarounds?"*  One might be to provide the property(s) as a hash value the app. requests from a servlet (or PHP, ASP..) on your server that supplies the 1000 char resource.  Have you searched the bug DB for other instances?  It might be worth raising a report if nothing exists.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the quick response. My search returned an old link https://forums.oracle.com/message/5500341#5500341 which mentions similar problem in java 1.6 itself, and the related bug http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6728843  is still open, but there is nothing in the update 45 revision history which tells me that something has changed in u45 which can impact this behavior.

Comment: @atulsm: Please update your question to include your findings.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for reminding. Updated the question with the findings.

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2593583

Answer (score 0):

Since i couldnt find any other way, i implemented a REST endpoint in the server and got the values i want by connecting to it.