# java client side application after updating java 7 - 25 to latest version 7 – 45 on client pc

Tags: java, client-side, jnlp

We have  a client side java application

It works fine for java 7 -25 update and earlier version on client computer. After  updating to java 7 – 45 , it no longer works when we try to launch the application by using .jnlp file.

Please give me some suggestions .

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is your application in a self-signed jar?  If so, I think the only way to run it would be to use the java control panel to lower security settings on the client computer.  Soon, the self-signed jars won't work at all (build 51 coming in January).

I have the same problem.  I think we have to get commercial certificates for this to continue to work.

Nina

Comment: hi nina, thank you for your response. i have 2 questions 1. what format of certificate we need pen or pks or others?  2. should we install on server side or clident side? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If its working in java7u25 and not working in 7u45, then it could be related to the properties in jnlp not getting propogated to application properly. Signing is not an issue yet, but soon will fail from 2014 jan onwards.

You have to start your property names with "jnlp.", and then in the applet load remove the "jnlp." from the property names. Refer [jnlp can no longer pass large properties since java 7 upgrade 45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487194/jnlp-can-no-longer-pass-large-properties-since-java-7-upgrade-45) and the discussions

Comment: i have tried add '.jnlp', but still does not work. stuck on this for several days, do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to debug your application in verbose mode to see whats happening. Use javaws -J-Xdebug -J-Xnoagent -J-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -verbose YourJNLP.jnlp